# Hosting ActiveX Controls in the .NET Compact Framework 2.0

Tags: .net-3.5, windows-mobile, compact-framework, activex, webbrowser-control

After following the method to Host the ActiveX Web Browser (webvw.idl) control in C#, we are struck in getting webview.dll file from the mobile device.

To create a complete class definition by using AxImp.exe we are unable to get the webview.dll from the windows mobile device, now how shall we proceed further, please help.

Thanks, 
Ramanand

Answer (score 1):

AxImp requires a type library. Run Visual Studio command prompt and go to in the pocket PC SDK include directory and execute

use [midl /D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367321(VS.85).aspx) UNDER_CE=$(CEVersion) webvw.idl 
here $(CEVersion) is your CE version, such as 0x420 or 0x600

There is a System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser class in .NET Compact Framework 2.0. The open sourced OpenNETCF SDF have an WebBrowser control class under the OpenNETCF.Windows.Forms namespace in version 1.4.

Comment: Thanks Sheng, But AxImp tool requires either .dll or .ocx file but either of these files of webvw.dll ATL ActiveX control cann't be accessed from either windows mobile device or through emulator.

Actually we want to host Webview ActiveX control into C#, in this progress we need to generate .cs files using AxIMp tool, here we are get stuck.

Comment: how about starting from OpenNETCF.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser? It is pretty good actually, better than System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser IMHO.